# Will a house become "invalid" if I cage it to to stop an NPC leaving?

Tags: terraria

I finally made an arena for [Moon Lord](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Moon_Lord). Since he killed me so many times (because it takes to much time to get to the Nurse), I decided to make a small "cage" over the Nurses' house, and teleport down when I need to heal. The thing is, she'll probably walk on the Teleporter and go up. I want to cage her in a spot just so she doesn't move so I can easily heal when I need to. But I don't know a thing. *Will* that make the house **invalid**?

I put the blocks already, and i will make them a little higher so the Nurse doesn't jump over the Glass and gets on the Teleporter.

Does anyone have an answer?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, this will not make the housing invalid. You could completely enclose the Nurse, as long as at least one tile is exposed to join the enclosure to the main room. But one problem you might have, is that placing blocks may change the location the Nurse stands at night, so if you move away from the arena (in order to fight the pillars per say) she may no longer be standing in the same location. - [George Willcox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/138319/george-willcox) in comments

Answer (score 0):

It will work. But if you go to far away, she might not be in the same spot!